# Update all divs in .each with class .hello except .hello in #thiscontainer

Tags: jquery, each

I have a simple .each loop, where I iterate through all divs with a certain class and change the content of that div.

How do I exclude changing content with that certain class within my current active container, which I have defined in `var currentActiveDiv`.

JS

```
var currentActiveDiv = $("container2");

$('.hello').each(function(index){
    $(this).html("bye");
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
<div id="container3">
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
<div id="container4">
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Expected result would be all divs printing out "bye" except `#container2`
http://jsfiddle.net/LLqj4k9m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `not` selector and then find all descendant elements.

`$('div:not(#container2) .hello')`

http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/1/

Comment: Cheers man - makes sense! What if the .hello class is nested within lots of other divs, is there some easy way to target then? Nested it simply here, but scenario is it's nested within 4-5 other divs
http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/2/

Answer (score 0):

First problem in your fiddle is that `currentActiveDiv` should be `$('#container2')` not `$('container2')`.

```
var currentActiveDiv = $("#container2");
$('.hello').each(function(index, value){
  var parent = $(value).parent();
  if (parent[0] !== currentActiveDiv[0]) {
    $(value).html('bye')
  }
})
```

Not the best code but, is clearly solves the problem.